# Jquery load file and auto select the option after files load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country").load("country.php",function(){        
        //Select the option from DB
        $('#country').val("<?PHP echo $country;?>");            
        //Load state option list
        switch($("#country").val()){
            case "aus":$("#state").load("aus_state.php",function(){
                $('#state').val("<?PHP echo $state;?>");
                switch($("#state").val()){
                    case "aus_ACT":$("#location").load("aus_ACT.php",function(){
                    $('#location').val("<?PHP echo $location;?>");
                    ...

                    });break
                    case "aus_NSW":$("#location").load("aus_NSW.php");break
                    case "aus_NT":$("#location").load("aus_NT.php");break
                    case "aus_QLD":$("#location").load("aus_QLD.php");break
                    case "aus_SA":$("#location").load("aus_SA.php");break
                    case "aus_TAS":$("#location").load("aus_TAS.php");break
                    case "aus_VIC":$("#location").load("aus_VIC.php");break
                    case "aus_WA":$("#location").load("aus_WA.php");break
                }
            });break
            case "eng":$("#state").load("eng_countie.php",function(){
                ...

            });break
            case "usa":$("#state").load("us_state.php",function(){
                ...

            });break
        }
    });
});
```

I hava a dynamic drop down select option.

[country]->[state]->[location]

I use jquery load the option list. However I need to auto select the option list for user to update. ex. [usa]->[CA]->[LA]

I put a function after the files load, `.load(file.php, function(){...})`

```
$('country').val("<?PHP echo data from DB; ?>")
```

switch state option list depend what value from DB...

Since I have a lots of sub list, this will be very hard to editing. Is any better way to do this?

something like

```
$("#country").val("<?PHP echo $country;?>").change(function(){
    switch($("#country").val()){
        case "aus":$("#state").load("aus_state.php");break
        case "eng":$("#state").load("eng_countie.php");break
        case "usa":$("#state").load("us_state.php");break
    }
});


$("#state").val("<?PHP echo $state;?>").change(function(){
    switch($("#state").val()){
        case "aus_ACT":$("#location").load("aus_ACT.php");break
        //...Put all countries's states here 
    }
});
```

it's complex, I try my best to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can build maps to identify state page (`aus_state.php`) from country code (`aus`), location page from state code, and some necessary deeper mappings. These maps can be constructed either from database or your project structure.

   ```js
   var mapping = {
       country_state: {
           aus: 'aus_state.php',
           eng: 'eng_countie.php',
           usa: 'us_state.php'
       },
       state_location: {
           aus_ACT: 'aus_ACT.php',
           aus_NSW: 'aus_NSW.php',
           ...
           // it seems that the state code has a country prefix
           // so you can merge all countries' locations in a map.
           usa_CA: 'usa_CA.php',
       }
   };
   ```
2. Rather than create all the JS code dynamically, you can write the static part in functions in a separate JS file and only use PHP to generate the changing part. And here only country/state/location changes. You can put the code at the bottom of your HTML page so that it get evaluated and initialized before the `$(document).ready` handler.

   ```js
   var selection_state = {
       country: "<?PHP echo $country;?>",
       state: "<?PHP echo $state;?>",
       location: "<?PHP echo $location;?>"
   };
   ```
3. Rewrite the loading/selecting logic in a separate JS file and load it in the HTML page with `<script src="..."></script>` tag.

   ```js
   $(function () {
       $('#country').load('country.php', function () {
           $('#country').val(selection_state.country);
           if (! mapping.country_state[selection_state.country])
               return;
           $('#state').load(mapping.country_state[selection_state.country], function () {
               $('#state').val(selection_state.state);
               if (! mapping.state_location[selection_state.state])
                   return;
               $('#location').load(mapping.state_location[selection_state.state], function () {
                   $('#location').val(selection_state.location);
               });
           });
       });
   });
   ```

   It seems that it's unnecessary that the loading of country/state/location to be sequential. You can perform the loading in parallel. (The code bellow has better performance but would have different behavior with the former one when some list failed to load.)

   ```js
   $(function () {
       $('#country').load('country.php', function () {
           $('#country').val(selection_state.country);
       });
       if (mapping.country_state[selection_state.country]) {
           $('#state').load(mapping.country_state[selection_state.country], function () {
               $('#state').val(selection_state.state);
           });
       }
       if (mapping.state_location[selection_state.state]) {
           $('#location').load(mapping.state_location[selection_state.state], function () {
               $('#location').val(selection_state.location);
           });
       }
   });
   ```

**PS.** For step 1, rather than requesting different page for different country/state, I think it's better to request only two pages to fetch the states/locations and pass the country code / state code as parameters. E.g. request `country_state.php?country=aus` for all the states in Australia(?). This will simplify the logic at both server and client side, and you will get cleaner project structure. With `mod_rewrite`, you can bind request of `aus_state.php` to `country_state.php?country=aus`, if necessary.